# Implementing change notifications in QAbstractItemModel with external source

Tags: qt, qt4, qabstractitemmodel

I'm implementing a `QAbstractItemModel` that represents data that can be changed externally. My model will receive the notification about the changed data after the change has occurred and I have no way of receiving a notification before the change occurs. By the time my model is notified of the change, the old data is not available anymore.

As far as I understand the documentation, the methods `beginInsertRows`, `beginRemoveRows` and such have to be called before the change, while the old data is still available.

Is my understanding correct? If so, what are my alternatives?